How to add bookmarks in html when using svelte-spa-router?
For many reasons, I can't use Sveltekit. So I'm using svelte-spa-router for my SPA.
The way you use the router is by adding hyperlinks like <a href="#about"/>. That makes the url www.domain.com/#about and mounts the respective component.
The issue is that, this is hijacking the default bookmark behavior. What do I do if I wanted the default behavior? I.e, to scroll down to a section with the  id="about" on clicking an anchor element?
Appreciate your help.

svelte-spa-router only supports URL hash routing. Either use another library or a framework, otherwise you're out of luck.

https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router/issues/157
